# APS.NET - Windows Authentication to Access SQL Server through the Web Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, windows-authentication

I'm creating something like an Intranet. Users today already access directly SQL Server using Windows Authentication, where security grants are set for each user, but I want to put the ASP.NET Web Server between these users and the database. I want the IIS to pass user's windows authentication credentials (from users accessing the website) to the SQL Sever.

Conditions:

- Both the Sql Server and the IIS are in the same domain.
- They are in different machines.

I've found [this](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_security/authentication/article.php/c7725/How-to-Use-Windows-Authentication-to-Access-SQL-Server-Through-a-ASPNET-Web-Application.htm) acticle which explains how to do that, but there is a disclaimer saying that SQL and IIS must be in the same machine.

Is there some way to do that given my conditions?

Comment: If on different machines I think you need to setup kerberos auth to pass the token along.

Answer (score 0):

The don't have to be the same machine, just make sure you have set up IIS to use Windows Authentication and also in your connection string connect as the windows user e.g.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseConnectionName" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=YourDataBaseName;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```